# jquery code to unselect all the asp.net checkbox by change event of the dropdownlist

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i have researched a lot,but none of the codes fire for me as 
(1).i want my checkboxes to be deselected which is placed in the div whenever change event is fired from dropdownlist and
(2)i want my div to be shown near or below the dropdown list
and my code is here and one imporatant thing i am working on the content page and (

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

) this is in the master page.
this is my content page

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/mstr-homepage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="frm-giveWork.aspx.cs" Inherits="giveWork" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style2 {
            width: 600px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#divapproval').hide();

            $(function () {
                $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlorderno').change(function () {
                    var selectedindex = document.getElementById("<%=ddlorderno.ClientID%>").selectedIndex;
                    if (selectedindex > 0) {
                        $('#divapproval').hide();
                        $('#divapproval').css({ 'position': 'absolute', 'border': '1px solid black', 'padding': '5px' });
                        $('#divapproval').show();
                        $("[class$=clsApproval]").attr("checked", true);

                    }
                });
            });

        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />

    <table align="center" class="auto-style2">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Select Order number"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td colspan="4">
                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Select name  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  and &nbsp;&nbsp;  enter description"></asp:Label>
            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlorderno" runat="server">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlkarname" runat="server">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtdescrip" runat="server" class="test"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit" Visible="false" OnClick="btnEdit_Click" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="btnsubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnsubmit_Click" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="divapproval" style="display: none;">
                    <table border="1">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" class="clsApproval" Text="coat" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" class="clsApproval" Text="pant" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server" class="clsApproval" Text="shirt" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox4" runat="server" class="clsApproval" Text="sherwani" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox5" runat="server" class="clsApproval" Text="modijacket" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>

            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:GridView ID="grdDetails" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">
                <iframe id="iLoadBillDetails" runat="server" width="700px" height="900px" src="frm-orderDetails.aspx"></iframe>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: i have also used '.prop('checked', true)' but this also does't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the DropDownList does not do a PostBack, you can do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#<%= DropDownList1.ClientID %>').change(function () {
        disableCheckBoxes();
    });

    function disableCheckBoxes() {
        $('#divapproval input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
            $(this).prop("checked", "");
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: the function disableCheckBoxes is firing but the ckeckboxes is not being unselected. plz see the aspx file as i have shared the whole file

Comment: I can guarantee it is working. Check if the ID of `divapproval` is the correct one.

Comment: yes sir you are right it is working,i was making a mistake by using both '$('#ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlorderno') and    var selectedindex = document.getElementById("<%=ddlorderno.ClientID%>").selectedIndex;'

Comment: can you plz tell me how to show my divapproval just below the dropdownlist1 as by using css it is showing way below the dropdownlist where it was originally placed at the design time

Comment: sorry, I don't understand what you mean? You can just move the HTML?

Answer (score 1):

You should do with `divapproval` the same thing you are doing with `ddlorderno`. So you can do this:

```
var div = $("#<%=divapproval.ClientID%>");  
div.hide();
div.css({  'position': 'absolute', 'border': '1px solid black', 'padding': '5px' });
div.show();
```

Then if you want to de-select you should set the checkboxes to checked false. I'd use a cleaner style there as well:

```
$(".clsApproval").attr("checked", false);
```

Comment: dear @kblok  '$(".clsApproval").attr("checked", false);'  this is not working as well, i don't know whats wrong .i have shared my whole aspx file plz check